# ALTER VIEW inserts database prefix for one view only

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Having a strange problem.

I use several db views in my app. All of the views just reference their tables without prefix the db name, e.g.

```
SELECT  `foo`, `bar`
FROM    `tablename`
```

However, I have one view which is as follows:

```
SELECT  `foo`, `bar`
FROM    `database_name`.`table_name`
```

This is causing headaches when performing schema comparisons.

I've edited the view several times using ALTER VIEW but every time it reinserts the database name as a prefix. I've also dropped and re-created it from scratch but same result.

It only does it for this one view though.

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3.10. Here's the full statement:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `reporting_base` AS
    SELECT 
        `b`.`creditor_id` AS `creditor_id`,
        `c`.`creditor_name` AS `creditor_name`,
        `c`.`group_name` AS `group_name`,
        `rd`.`base_date` AS `base_date`,
        `rd`.`year` AS `year`,
        `rd`.`period` AS `period`,
        `rd`.`week` AS `week`,
        `b`.`id` AS `branch_id`,
        `b`.`branch_name` AS `branch_name`,
        `b`.`area` AS `area`,
        `b`.`manager` AS `manager`,
        `s`.`id` AS `staff_id`,
        `s`.`type` AS `staff_type`,
        `s`.`full_name` AS `staff_name`
    FROM
        (((`database_name`.`reporting_dates` `rd`
        JOIN `database_name`.`branches` `b`)
        JOIN `database_name`.`creditors` `c` ON (((`c`.`id` = `b`.`creditor_id`)
            AND (`c`.`include_in_reports` = 1))))
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            0 AS `id`,
                `database_name`.`creditors`.`id` AS `creditor_id`,
                'n/a' AS `type`,
                'n/a' AS `full_name`
        FROM
            `database_name`.`creditors` UNION SELECT 
            `database_name`.`staff`.`id` AS `id`,
                `database_name`.`staff`.`creditor_id` AS `creditor_id`,
                `database_name`.`staff`.`type` AS `type`,
                `database_name`.`staff`.`full_name` AS `full_name`
        FROM
            `database_name`.`staff`) `s` ON ((`s`.`creditor_id` = `c`.`id`)))
    WHERE
        (`rd`.`base_date` <= UTC_DATE())
```

Comment: Before `Alter view` select `database_name` as default db. So that db name will not be appended when its altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is ambiguity in the whole create view statement...it may add database name.

```
...from (((''table1' 'rd' 
join 'dbname'.'table2' 'b'...
```

itself is enough to trigger 'dbname' into the view code.

Comment: When I remove all references to the database it still does it, there shouldn't be ambiguity

Comment: Got a solution?